# How do I change my OpenGL object color only when I touch it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es

I am trying to change my OpenGL square's color only when it is touched. I looked around online at some good sources to see how I could find the coordinates to change its color, [Converting pixel co-ordinates to normalized co-ordinates at draw time in OpenGL 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194750/converting-pixel-co-ordinates-to-normalized-co-ordinates-at-draw-time-in-opengl). However, I am still confused about how to get my square's or onTouchEvent inputs coordinates to be translated in OpenGL code(vertexShaderCode). I have tried to directly track my square coordinates in the onTouchEvent activity, but it wrongly tracks the position since I am working with two different coordinate systems(OpenGl, Android Studios).

```
//THIS IS NOT MY FULL CODE
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
        // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
        // interested in events where the touch position changed.
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        colorHolder = renderer.getmSquare().getColor();

        switch (e.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //THIS IS MY PROBLEM. I DON'T KNOW A GOOD WAY OF TRACKING THE SQUARE'S POSITION BESIDES
                //ADDING VARIBLE TO IT'S MAIN CLASS THEN REFERENCING THEM HERE
                if(renderer.mSquareY > (y / getHeight()) && renderer.mSquareX > (x / getWidth()))
                    renderer.getmSquare().color = tempColor;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                float dx = x - previousX;
                float dy = y - previousY;

                float tempHeight = y / getHeight();
                float tempWidth = x / getWidth();

                //THIS IS MY PROBLEM. I DON'T KNOW A GOOD WAY OF TRACKING THE SQUARE'S POSITION BESIDES ADDING VARIBLE TO IT'S MAIN CLASS THEN REFERENCING THEM HERE
                if(renderer.mSquareY < (y / getHeight()) && renderer.mSquareX < (x / getWidth()))
                    renderer.getmSquare().color = tempColor;
                
                renderer.mSquareX = (x / getWidth());
                renderer.mSquareY = (y / getHeight());
                ...
```

I have three classes that handle creating the square, handles rendering, and the main activity in the corresponding order: Square.java, MyGLRenderer.java, MyGLSurfaceView.java.

```java
public class Square {

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
            // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    // The matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position.
                    // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                    // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "}";
    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;

    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float squareCoords[] = {
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

    private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    public float[] getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(float[] color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    float color[] = { 0.2f, 0.709803922f, 0.898039216f, 1.0f };

    public Square() {
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                squareCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
                drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
        int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
    }

    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        //MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        //MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");
        // Draw the square
        GLES20.glDrawElements(
                GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private Triangle mTriangle;

    public Square getmSquare() {
        return mSquare;
    }

    public void setmSquare(Square mSquare) {
        this.mSquare = mSquare;
    }

    private Square   mSquare;
    private Circle   mCircle;

    // vPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
    private final float[] vPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] translationMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] scaleMatrix = new float[16];

    public volatile float mAngle;

    public float mSquareX = 1.5f;
    public float mSquareY = 0.0f;
    public float mRadius = 1.0f;

    public float getAngle() {
        return mAngle;
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        mAngle = angle;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig eglconfig) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // initialize a triangle
        mTriangle = new Triangle();
        // initialize a square
        mSquare = new Square();
        // initialize a square
        mCircle = new Circle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        float[] scratch = new float[16];
        float[] movementSquare = new float[16];
        float[] scaleCircle = new float[16];

        float tempscaleFactor = 1.0f * mRadius;

        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(vPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);

        // Create a rotation transformation for the triangle
        //long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
        //float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
        Matrix.setRotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);

        Matrix.setIdentityM(translationMatrix,0);
        Matrix.translateM(translationMatrix, 0, mSquareX, mSquareY,0);

        //THIS PROBLEM HERE IS THAT MY CIRCLE TRANSLATE'S ON THE X-AXIS WHEN SCALING. MY GOAL IS TO TRY AND KEEP IT IN PLACE WHILE IT'S BEING SCALED. Y-AXIS HAS NOT ISSUES
        Matrix.setIdentityM(scaleMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.scaleM(scaleMatrix, 0, mRadius, mRadius, 0);
        if(mRadius != 1f)
            Matrix.translateM(scaleMatrix, 0, -(1 + (mRadius / 2)),0,0);

        // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
        // Note that the vPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
        // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
        Matrix.multiplyMM(movementSquare, 0, vPMatrix, 0, translationMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, vPMatrix, 0, rotationMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scaleCircle, 0, vPMatrix, 0, scaleMatrix, 0);

        // Draw shape
        mTriangle.draw(scratch);
        mSquare.draw(movementSquare);
        mCircle.draw(scaleCircle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width / height;

        // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
        // in the onDrawFrame() method
        Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 7);
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find some help in the answers to [Is it possible get which surface of cube will be click in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893277/is-it-possible-get-which-surface-of-cube-will-be-click-in-opengl/45946943#45946943) and [OpenGL - Mouse coordinates to Space coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749675/opengl-mouse-coordinates-to-space-coordinates/46752492#46752492).